# Como coloco de manera correcta un array de array para sacar información de cada elemento?

Tags: swift, swift3

```
import UIKit
class Pantalla1: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
let nombres = [["Restaurante1", "Restaurante2", "Restaurante3", "Restaurante4", "Restaurante5"], ["Hotel1", "Hotel2", "Hotel3", "Hotel4", "Hotel5"], ["Bar1", "Bar2", "Bar3", "bar4", "bar5",  "bar5", "bar5", "bar5", "bar5", "bar5"]]


let secciones = ["Restaurantes", "Hoteles", "Bares"]


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    return secciones[section];
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return self.secciones.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

return self.nombres[section].count

}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:UITableViewCell=UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier:"Cell")
     cell.textLabel?.text = self.nombres[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    if indexPath.section == 0 {

        cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named :"restaurantes.png")
    }

    if indexPath.section == 1 {

        cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named :"hoteles.png")
    }

    if indexPath.section == 2 {

        cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named :"bares.png")
    }


    return cell

}

func colorForIndex(index: Int) -> UIColor {
    let itemCount = nombres.count - 1
    let color = (CGFloat(index) / CGFloat(itemCount)) * 0.6
    return UIColor(red: 1.0, green: color, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell,
                        forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor = colorForIndex(index: indexPath.row)
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let idItemSeleccionado = [indexPath.row] [indexPath.section]

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "infoMariscal", sender: idItemSeleccionado)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "infoMariscal" {

        let idItemSeleccionadoRecibido = sender as! Int


        let itemMariscal: Mariscal = segue.destination as! Mariscal

        itemMariscal.nombreItemRecibido = nombres [idItemSeleccionadoRecibido](aqui me sale error al poner nombres)

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Deberías indicar cuál es el problema y qué has intentado para solventarlo. Sin esta información no podemos ayudarte.

Comment: cuando hagas el `performSegue` pasa `indexPath` en el `sender` para luego en `prepare` accedes al item asi: `nombes[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]` hazme saber si funciono asi?